# How to resolve the error "Base table or view not found"?

Tags: 8, database

When I connect my custom module with database external

```
$database = array(
  'host' => 'localhost', 
  'database' => 'DATABASE1',
  'username' => 'root', 
  'password' => 'root', 
  'driver' => 'mysql',
);
Database::addConnectionInfo('mykey', 'default', $database);
   db_set_active('mykey');
```

it gives error on running the module

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146
>   Table 'DATABASE1.filter_format' doesn't exist: SELECT
>   ff.* FROM {filter_format} ff WHERE (status =
>   :db_condition_placeholder_0) ORDER BY weight ASC; Array (
>   [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => 1 ) in filter_formats() (line 434
>   of /var/www/html/drupalprac/modules/filter/filter.module).
>
> Uncaught exception thrown in shutdown function.
>
> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146
>   Table 'DATABASE1.semaphore' doesn't exist: DELETE FROM
>   {semaphore} WHERE (value = :db_condition_placeholder_0) ; Array (
>   [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => 1595456215ac3545f2ff1c3.60338979 )
>   in lock_release_all() (line 269 of
>   /var/www/html/drupalprac/includes/lock.inc). Uncaught exception thrown
>   in session handler.
>
> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146
>   Table 'DATABASE1.sessions' doesn't exist: SELECT 1 AS
>   expression FROM {sessions} sessions WHERE ( (sid =
>   :db_condition_placeholder_0) AND (ssid = :db_condition_placeholder_1)
>   ); Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] =>
>   gSAxKMpfVXzf2EVP4EWBtuF2klcg0RZie30ztTTUjKc
>   [:db_condition_placeholder_1] => ) in _drupal_session_write() (line
>   209 of /var/www/html/drupalprac/includes/session.inc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to switch the database back before it carries out any operation that requires the Drupal database.

```
// Switch to your custom database.
db_set_active('mykey');

// Work with that database (select/insert/update).
...

// Switch back, before you use the Drupal API again
db_set_active();
```

Comment: I have already done this in my code after the return statement but getting this error

Comment: There's no `return` statement in your code. But regardless, logically speaking, you must be doing something that requires the Drupal database connection before you switch it back again. Refactor your code so that the only thing you're doing in between switching away from then back to the Drupal DB connection is database operations. Nothing using the Drupal API

Comment: I created a function in my custom module where firstly I set active external database then sending a query to retrieve data and print it in tabular theme form the after return statement of function, switch back to the default database. So where m i wrong? Please help

Comment: See the answer, that's as much as I can possibly tell you from the information you've provided